# READ PHONE STATE

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

**What i have:** a function that is checking the state of my device. Now, in the case `READ_PHONE_STATE` I have put a function that I want to run when I get any voice call on my number, but it\s not working the way I want and causing Force Close the application. 
Here is my code:

```
public void readPhoneState() {
    // Create a new PhoneStateListener
    listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    Log.e("DEBUG", "IDLE");
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    Log.e("DEBUG", "OFF_HOOK");
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    myFunction();                                                                                           
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    // Register the listener with the telephony manager
    telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

I just want this function to run in `PHONE_STATE_RINGING`. How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace from logcat?

Comment: @dave.c.. its done now
I first checked my call state then put a switch on that and in each state i implemented my methods that i wanted to.